# How to edit translate3d in Swiper Slider

Tags: css, swiper.js

I use Swiper Slider in my page, the pict is like this:

[image]

I want my page like this:

[image]

after that I inspect it, I understand that what I have to edit is the translate,

```html
<div class="swiper-wrapper" style="transition-duration: 0ms; transform: translate3d(152.5px, 0px, 0px);">
```

However, I am surprised, I have never edited that section but there is a translation value there.

How do I edit the value so that my slider display is as desired?

Answer (score 7):

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    centeredSlides: false,
});
```

at your Swiper JS change centeredSlides from true to false.

Answer (score 0):

You'le need to debug the header of your website.

I think that this is the problem.
box-sizing or whatever

Comment: when i change the translate3d value, the view is like i want, but i dont know to change default translate3d

Comment: Go into your code and search him by doing ctrl+F and translate3d then change it

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can edit the translate3D per se, however I was able to solve my problem by adding a margin to the last Swiper slide element.

```
.swiper-wrapper li:last-of-type{
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

This was enough to make Swiper recalculate the translate3D with a nice margin.